# Maven build failure : could not transfer metadata

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to run maven clean install but i got these errors and warnings

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/1): Cannot access http://download.java.net/maven/1 with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
[WARNING] The POM for javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.7 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring-support:jar:2.0.8 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:jar:2.6.10 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:3.7.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.6.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.1-FINAL is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
--
[WARNING] /D:/projet/perWeb/per/perTools/src/main/java/ma/archostechnology/swk/report/PDFReportingService.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /D:/projet/perWeb/per/perTools/src/main/java/ma/archostechnology/swk/report/PDFReportingService.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 2 warnings 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error reading D:\Fa\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading D:\Fa\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.1.7\jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading D:\Faa\repository\org\springframework\spring-support\2.0.8\spring-support-2.0.8.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading    D:\Fa\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading D:\Fa\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4.1\mail-1.4.1.jar; error in opening zip file
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>per</artifactId>
        <groupId>ma.archostechnology</groupId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ma.archostechnology</groupId>
    <artifactId>perTools</artifactId>
    <name>Projet PER Tools</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.1-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-vfs</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-vfs</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.objectlab.kit</groupId>
            <artifactId>datecalc-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.objectlab.kit</groupId>
            <artifactId>datecalc-jdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
           <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
           <version>51.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Maven 2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Maven 1 Repository (legacy)</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
            <layout>legacy</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jfrog-plugins</id>
            <name>jfrog-plugins-dist</name>
            <url>
                http://www.jfrog.org/artifactory/plugins-releases@repo
            </url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>localrepository</id>
            <name>localrepository</name>
            <url>D:\FatimaZahra\repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
            <layout>legacy</layout>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

When i run the mvn -X compile i got this

```
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin version for org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in local (D:\FatimaZahra\repository)
[DEBUG] Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in http://download.java.net/maven/2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2-repository.dev.java.net has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file D:\FatimaZahra\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\cobertura-maven-plugin\resolver-status.properties
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/1): Cannot access http://download.java.net/maven/1 with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/1): Cannot access http://download.java.net/maven/1 with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$1.execute(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetadata(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveMetadata(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolveFromRepository(DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecyclePluginResolver.resolveMissingPluginVersions(LifecyclePluginResolver.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access http://download.java.net/maven/1 with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:603)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access http://download.java.net/maven/1 with type legacy using the available layout factories: Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:113)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryLayoutException: Cannot access http://download.java.net/maven/1 with type legacy using the available layout factories: Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryLayoutProvider.newRepositoryLayout(DefaultRepositoryLayoutProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:107)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryLayoutException: Unsupported repository layout legacy
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory.newInstance(Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryLayoutProvider.newRepositoryLayout(DefaultRepositoryLayoutProvider.java:111)
    ... 33 more
```

I've already tried to delete the repository and i'm not using any proxy.
Is there anything i'm missing? Could you help me please

Comment: Could you please post the full pom, or at least repositories section.

Comment: Take a look at you `<repositories></repositories>` 2 of them result in 404 - page not found and the URL in `jfrog-plugins` redirects to jfrog default page.

Comment: I've changed the urls and i used https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/ but i still get the same errors

Comment: When you've run maven against broken repositories, maven saved the `pom` files from all your dependencies. Only they're not valid pom files but rather html replies. [Clear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache) your cache before your re-run maven.

Comment: Note that your `pluginRepositories` also contain dead links.

Comment: Yes thanks i cleared the cache and now it's working just fine

Comment: Try printing `<path-to-m2>/.m2/repository/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/51.1/icu4j-51.1.pom` and you'll see that it's a html file.

Comment: @JanezKuhar clearing cache solves the issue. Wish I saw your comment earlier. Thank you! Chaymae, you can accept the corresponding answer so that it's visible to larger audience. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong URLs for the repos. Please check [this page](https://maven2-repository.java.net/) and choose the right one.

Comment: I've changed the url but still it doesn't work i got the same errors

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was a false certificate inside the JDK i used.

Answer (score 3):

This issue was solved after I cleared the maven cache, namely deleted `Users\<username>\.m2\repository` (which is [safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991279/3190576) to delete) and rebuilt again.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of struggle, I just reinstalled java and the thing was fixed.