# Failed to download spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a Spring project using Intellij Idea Ultimate 2018.1, after selecting the addition libraries and click the finish button getting an error.

[image: error]

Please help me, Thanks!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891. I'd suggest to use Spring Initializr to create the project instead. https://start.spring.io/.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are multiple possible reasons for this error.

1.Check whether Firewall or antivirus software is blocking Maven from downloading artifacts.If yes then disable it.

2.Internet connection interrupted in middle of downloading the jar files.

3.try to install from scratch by clearing/deleting the .m2 repository and then `mvn install`

[How to clear .m2 Maven folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991258/how-to-clear-m2-maven-folder)

Comment: Not working - Disabled the antivirus, i have a good internet connection and also deleted the .m2 maven folder.

Comment: Try to reimport the project